# Can an embedded winform chart be bound to an observable collection in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I wanted to embed a winform chart control in a WPF window which shall be bound to an observablecollection filled by entering data in a WPF DataGrid.
The observablecollection is needed because i fill it by using a WPF-DataGrid in which i can insert or update data.

So i added to my WPF-project the following dependencies:
- System.Windows.Forms
- System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

For a first test i hardcoded in the constructor of the WPF window some data in the observablecollection and bound the chart control.
In that case the display in the chart works fine.

But in the final version i want to insert and/or update data in the DataGrid and the chart shall display that data all at once.
Is it possible to manage that?

Here is the code for the window and the classes as example.

The WPF window MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="StepFunctions.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:winformchart="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StepFunctions"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="StepFunctions"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="maingrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--DataGrid for insert and update of step function data-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="grd_stepdata"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Margin="5"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  RowEditEnding="grd_stepdata_RowEditEnding"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding StepDataSource, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_LowerComparer" Binding="{Binding LowerComparer, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Lower comparer"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_LowerBound" Binding="{Binding LowerBound, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Lower bound"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_StepValue" Binding="{Binding StepValue, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Value"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <!--Chart for displaying the step function data-->
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Margin="5">
            <winformchart:Chart x:Name="myWinformChart"
                                Dock="Fill">
                <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                    <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
                </winformchart:Chart.Series>
                <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                    <winformchart:ChartArea/>
                </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
            </winformchart:Chart>
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <!--Button for test-->
        <Button x:Name="btn_do"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="5"
                Click="btn_do_Click">Do it</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind of MainWindow.xaml:

```
using StepFunctions.ViewModels;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace StepFunctions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = vm;

            // These lines are just for the first test.
            // Normally these lines would be out-commented.
            AddStepdata();
            ChartDataRefresh();
        }

        // When the user leaves a DataGrid-row after insert or update the chart shall be refreshed.
        private void grd_stepdata_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            ChartDataRefresh();
        }

        private void AddStepdata()
        {
            vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 10, 1));
            vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 100, 2));
            vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 1000, 3));
        }

        private void ChartDataRefresh()
        {
            myWinformChart.DataSource = vm.StepDataSource;
            myWinformChart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "LowerBound";
            myWinformChart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "StepValue";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For testing the refresh of the chart after the window was loaded.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btn_do_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddStepdata();
            ChartDataRefresh();
        }

    }
}
```

The viewmodel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace StepFunctions.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Eventhandler for signalising that a property has changed.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<StepData> stepdataSource = new ObservableCollection<StepData>();

        public ObservableCollection<StepData> StepDataSource
        {
            get { return stepdataSource; }
            set
            {
                stepdataSource = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StepDataSource");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Informs the target which is bound to a property, that it's source was changed and that it shall update.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

And finally the class StepData which is the base for the observablecollection:

```
namespace StepFunctions.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for data of stepfunctions.
    /// </summary>
    public class StepData
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public StepData()
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        public StepData(string lowerComparer, double lowerBound, double stepValue)
        {
            LowerComparer = lowerComparer;
            LowerBound = lowerBound;
            StepValue = stepValue;
        }

        public string LowerComparer { get; set; }

        public double LowerBound { get; set; }

        public double StepValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it should work just the same,as you are calling `ChartDataRefresh` on `grd_stepdata_RowEditEnding`. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem is that when i call the method "ChartDataRefresh" only while the button-click-event the chart doesn't update. What i see is a white eagle on a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
The chart has to be generated in code-behind, not in the XAML.

So the method ChartDataRefresh has to look like that:

```
private void ChartDataRefresh()
{
    Chart myWinformChart = new Chart();
    myWinformChart.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    Series mySeries = new Series("series");
    mySeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    myWinformChart.Series.Add(mySeries);
    ChartArea myArea = new ChartArea();
    myWinformChart.ChartAreas.Add(myArea);
    myWinformChart.DataSource = vm.StepDataSource;
    myWinformChart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "LowerBound";
    myWinformChart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "StepValue";
    host.Child = myWinformChart;
}
```

While entering data in the WPF-DataGrid the Winform chart control is refreshed and the data displayed as a line for checking if the given data is correct.